# Create a line graph per minute in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to create a graph/chart that shows everything per minute.

In Excel normal chart maker, instead of per minute in the graph, it shows it every per 3 minutes:

[image: Link for chart]

My data:

```
tweets | minute
134 | 2
128 | 3
199 | 4
222 | 5
```

How can I do this per minute and also make a dot on the tweets per minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your graph is actually displaying all of your data points ("per minute") but the scale of your axis label is too large for all numbers to be displayed. You should be able to decrease the font size of those labels and view each number.

To decrease font size, click on one of the numbers (it should select them all) and press `CTRL + SHIFT + <`

Showing the "dots" where each data point lies on the line is a styling option called Data Markers. You can read about editing that property here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-data-markers-in-a-line-scatter-or-radar-chart-8e91c157-1c9c-4852-9657-1e2e1317f415

Comment: Thank you. I got it working now! https://imgur.com/a/vITMfn8